# How to authenticate user in Symfony2 with multiple databases

Tags: authentication, symfony

I'm using Symfony2 to authenticate users.
And I have two databases to store user information, db1 and db2.
The user table is stored in both databases, like username, password
How can I authenticate a user using both databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom user provider (and inject in it your 2 entity managers), you check the first database, if your user isn't in it you check the second one.

Comment: so you can validate my answer maybe